# Logger is not working in play framework scala?

Tags: scala, logging, playframework

Please find my application.conf and logback.xml

```
app {
  baseUrl = ""
  username = ""
  password = ""
  clientId = ""
}
```

logback.xml:

```
<!-- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/SettingsLogger -->
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNCFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </appender>

  <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="application" level="INFO" />

  <!-- Off these ones as they are annoying, and anyway we manage configuration ourselves -->
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />

  <root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCFILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

I have used the library import.play.api.Logger and also used logger.info("test") in my code.But I am not getting any logs from my application?

Comment: Can you include an example of how you are creating the logger object?

Comment: I found it just now. I have to change the WARN to INFO in root level tag in logback.xml

Comment: Ok.... now it seems that is is time to remove your question...

Answer (score 0):

I am materializing the answer provided by user3278612 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3278612/user3278612).

Change the root level from `WARN` to `INFO` to see more output:

```xml
<configuration>

  <!-- Before WARN -->
  <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="ASYNCFILE" />
      <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```